# Why doesn't the IE11 Developer Tools work?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I can press f12 or right click and select inspect element but when the toolbar opens it is just a blank white screen. I am able to view source on the broken f12 tools and this is what i see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
        <title>F12 Tools</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css" data-plugin-theme="true"/>

        <!-- Daytona Includes -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/plugin.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/CommonMinimal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="HeaderMerged.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // The main entry point
            F12.Host.Header.App.main();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="f12Logo"></div>
        <nav id="tabContainer">
            <div id="prevTabButton" class="tabNavButton tabNavButtonDisabled"></div>
            <div id="tabListContainer">
                <ul id="tabList">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="nextTabButton" class="tabNavButton tabNavButtonDisabled"></div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the head of this script i see it calling on a few javascript files and i cannot locate any matching files on my system.

I have win7 Home. Any help please. Am i even in the right ballpark to assume i don't have the necessary filesystem?

If it helps in my several attempts to fix the problem i have gotten a light blue color background with what looks like an inset box shadow around it. this goes away after a few seconds and back to the white blank screen.

Also I heard that there may be some registry fix so I'm going to dig in there.
I didn't really find anything in there.

Comment: You could try the "Reset Internet Explorer settings" option.  It's in the "Advanced" tab in Internet Options.

Comment: In reply to Don: I did that and restarted my computer. Started up IE11 and got that blue screen. And in Reply to Userpassword if it is a feature then is there any means to enable it that you know of?

Comment: If it is A feature how do I get it working?

Comment: Those files are embedded in the DLL "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\F12Resources.dll" so you shouldn't be able to see them on your disk. It sounds like either your install has gone wrong and either files or the registration is corrupt somehow. Which typically can only be fixed by a restore point. Either that or a virus scanner is running and blocking something.

Comment: for some reason half the options including the inspector in the f12 tools have just disappeared leaving the profiler and camera. One has to wonder if MS is trying to piss off the developers from using their products.

Answer (score 5):

I had the latest IE update installed and it didn't work for me, had to install [Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 (KB3008923)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45134)

Comment: this fixed it for me

Comment: ridiculous. only InternetExploder.exe could result in such a scenario

Answer (score 2):

I actually had this problem this morning.  In case anyone else found this occurring to them, I just had to update my IE 11 through Windows Update and it was all there when I restarted IE.